# Edição de pergunta

Tags: suporte

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301664/como-posso-selecionar-uma-faixa-de-itens-depois-de-alguns-valores-utilizando-op/301666?noredirect=1#comment612335_301666) o OP fez uma pergunta inicial, respondi de forma que atende o que ele necessita. Logo depois ele editou a pergunta pois não conseguiu expressar o que realmente queria e acabou fazendo com que minha resposta não respondesse a pergunta.

Devo apagar a resposta? O OP deveria criar outra pergunta? Ou devo editar a resposta adicionando a resposta para a edição do OP?

> OBS: Depois que ele alterou a pergunta outro usuário respondeu
>   atendendo a novo dúvida

.